# Searching for questions without a certain tag

Tags: support, searching

Is it possible to search the main site for questions which do not have a certain tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is doable with the existing search. Tags are indicated by square brackets, and a - sign indicates that the term which follows should not be present in the search results. Searching for "topology -[ag.algebraic-geometry]" (without the quotes) finds all questions containing the word "topology" and lacking the tag [ag.algebraic-geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ag.algebraic-geometry).

Incidentally, to restrict to only questions with a certain tag, the same style of syntax works, so a search for "topology [ag.algebraic-geometry]" will find all questions containing "topology" and with the tag [ag.algebraic-geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ag.algebraic-geometry).